# MaterialDesign Underline Color Of TextBox in Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, material-design, underline

I have more than one `TextBox`. I want to change the underlines depending on special circumstances. I'm using the MaterialDesign style. I want to change the underline of the `TextBox`. It's a feasible situation in XAML, but how can I do it in code-behind? `TextboxName.Underline` cannot be found.

My xaml code

```
<TextBox x:Name="Pulse2" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintTextBox}" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
         Foreground="{Binding Foreground, ElementName=CardID}" Height="43" Width="132" IsReadOnly="True"
         materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.UnderlineBrush="{Binding Background, ElementName=HaltButton}"
         materialDesign:HintAssist.Foreground="#244886"
         AcceptsReturn="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
         materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Pulse2" Margin="281,136,0,0"/>
```

Not Found

```
Pulse.Underline !!!
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the setter for the `UnderlineBrush` property on `TextFieldAssist` to set any `Brush` e.g.:

```
TextFieldAssist.SetUnderlineBrush(Pulse2, Brushes.Black);
```

Comment: Thanks I have also facing same issue. I have handled it in my code behind C# in constructor and its working fine thanks.

Answer (score 0):

thatguy,

```
TextFieldAssist.DecorationVisibility(txtLastName, (MainWindow.btnEditing == Enums.Editing.View) ? "Hidden" : "Visible");
```

error CS0103 "The name 'TextFieldAssist' does not exist in the current context!!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: My question is how can I behind Code modify MaterialDesign's "TextFieldAssist.DecorationVisibility"? Tried with the above solution but got error CS103 !

Comment: You should post this as a new question and not as an answer.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30780463)